# Sharepoint 2007 Create a dynamic teamsite that filters the content according to AD groups

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am currently trying to create a site that filter the content based on AD groups divide by company names.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It was very simple. 
Create individual lists for each company
Add the web part of each individual lists to a page
permission them by Target Audiences.